# Discounts are not working if we hide Javascript code

Tags: configurable-product, shipping, discount, product-view

To display discounts for each associate simple products we used this [module](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)

after installing, **only for configurable Products** we didn't got shipping charges for normal "Add to cart" button, but worked for Ajax add to cart button. [custom shipping method]

when we hide below JS code , than we are getting shipping charges for normal "Add to cart" also.

But if we hide , than we don't get proper discounts for each associate simple products.

```
    Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.reloadPriceLabels = function(productPriceIsKnown) {
        var priceFromLabel = '';
        var prodForm = $('product_addtocart_form');

/* This code is mainly responsible - start*/
        if (!productPriceIsKnown && typeof spConfig != "undefined") {
            priceFromLabel = spConfig.config.priceFromLabel;
        }
/* This code is mainly responsible -end */

        var priceSpanId = 'configurable-price-from-' + this.productId;
        var duplicatePriceSpanId = priceSpanId + this.duplicateIdSuffix;

        if($(priceSpanId) && $(priceSpanId).select('span.configurable-price-from-label'))
            $(priceSpanId).select('span.configurable-price-from-label').each(function(label) {
            label.innerHTML = priceFromLabel;
        });

        if ($(duplicatePriceSpanId) && $(duplicatePriceSpanId).select('span.configurable-price-from-label')) {
            $(duplicatePriceSpanId).select('span.configurable-price-from-label').each(function(label) {
                label.innerHTML = priceFromLabel;
            });
        }
    };
```

**Particularly below 2 lines of code is responsible for this :**

```
if (!productPriceIsKnown && typeof spConfig != "undefined") {
        priceFromLabel = spConfig.config.priceFromLabel;
 }
```

complete code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/17c2d65603b5d21a8d7c)

Comment: could you share you url of the PDP

Comment: please check here : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem with configurable product  simply add check for that

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getType()!='configure')
  { ?>
if (!productPriceIsKnown && typeof spConfig != "undefined") {
        priceFromLabel = spConfig.config.priceFromLabel;
 }

<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: i tried placing this code in view.phtml and scpoptions.phtml [extenison ] but i got error.

Comment: updated the code.. try that..

Comment: i added the code in top of view.phtml , but its displaying on view page as [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)